# No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder' has been registered

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am building brand new Web APIs with .NET core 2.2. In my `Startup.cs` I have set `ILoggerFactory` in configure method. When I do such a thing and add following code

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole();
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

I get information saying that this method is obsolete and it will be removed in future versions, instead I should use `ILoggingBuilder`.No problem, I have replaced  with this new logging method and as soon as I start Web APIs I get error

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder' has been registered.

and my output window shows this

> Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder' for the parameter 'loggingBuilder' of method.

I am new to .NET core, but am I missing something here? With ILoggerFactury, I did not have to register any services and logging would work just fine. [Microsoft's documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggingbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is not really helpful.

Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
    {
        loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        loggingBuilder.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler();
        }
        app.UseMvc();

        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        //});
    }
}
```

Program.cs looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Are you using `ConfigureLogging` on the `IWebHostBuilder`? Can you show some more code?

Comment: @John I am still learning a bit, I have added my startup.cs and program.cs code to this. I don't know I have to do more modifications to those files as with logging factory works just fine with this code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not working because you're not registering the logging components with your dependency injection container. There are two ways you can do this:

Either configure it as part of the `CreateWebHostBuilder`:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Or, alternatively, register it with your service collection under `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddDebug();
});
```

Comment: I can do it this way, this works well but it looks to me that kind of goes against the way .net is setup. Grouping all application setup should go under Configure method. There is nothing wrong going the other way, it is more like preference, but in my case it does not work and I am looking forward to why is not working and what piece is missing.

Comment: @zuboje Updated my answer. I see what you're saying about stuff should go under the "Configure" method, but [the "official" Microsoft way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) seems to be to use `.ConfigureLogging`. The alternative is to register it against the DI container yourself. The reason `ConfigureServices` is separate is that you can change it to return an `IServiceProvider` and thereby use your own DI container (I use Autofac).

Comment: I get this same error. I've tried adding both of these things and I still get the same exception. Using the very latest Core 2.2

Comment: @Matt Can you chuck your Program and Startup files into a pastebin and I'll take a look?

Comment: @John https://pastebin.com/EW61GiWL you are very kind. thank you for spending some of your time with me. For now, I feel like the way Microsoft has implemented DI is much more complicated than Java or Spring (or Spring.Net)

Comment: @Matt I think the issue comes from the `LoggingBuilder` code you have in `Configure`.  Since you are already setting up the logging in `ConfigureServices` (one of the correct places to do this), you can remove references to `ILoggingBuilder`, etc. from `Configure` - also remove the method parameter since it doesn't belong. Note that the interface which creates loggers (as opposed to configuring logging) is `ILoggerFactory`.

Comment: @John you are a saint! I could not get to that point because the method parameter was blowing up the Configure method. I removed that as well as your other suggestions. It is now working. Thank you!