# Issues using Log4Net.AspNetCore with ILoggingBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration, asp.net-core-2.2

ASP.NET Core 2.2 built-in providers do not appear to include a file provider. As such, I am opting to use log4net for now. However when I try to use the ILoggingBuilder class to create my logging service with the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging it doesn't look like Log4Net is able to find its configuration file. Here is a summary of my code and what I have done so far:

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;

        _logger.LogInformation("Starting Container . . .");
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Configuring DI Services . . .");

        services.AddLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddLog4Net();
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Configuring Application . . .");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/");
        });

        _logger.LogInformation("Web Application Startup Completed . . .");
    }
}
```

log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="WebSiteDI.log" />
      <maximumFileSize value="500KB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I have followed the instructions according to the Log4Net.AspCoreNet Github page ([Link](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/blob/develop/doc/CONFIG.md)). However this implementation does not appear to be able to locate the configuration file until I include the following in my startup:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

I know there is an options package that will allow me to do overrides and additional configuration in the appconfig.json (and will allow me to use the environment switching capabilities of the host container), but this isn't mentioned as required and still depends on log4net.config to be found.

Could the Github page be out of date or am I missing something?

Comment: It also says, "Add the AddLog4Net() call into your Configure method of the Startup class." I don't see that in your code.

Comment: In their example they pass an ILoggerFactory into configure and have these lines in Configure: var loggingOptions = this.Configuration.GetSection("Log4NetCore")
                                               .Get<Log4NetProviderOptions>();
        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net(loggingOptions);

Comment: I'm already doing that in the configure services. Doing it in the Configure method will break the code with the following Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder' for the parameter 'loggingBuilder' of method 'Configure' on type. This has been covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844561/no-service-for-type-microsoft-extensions-logging-iloggingbuilder-has-been-regi/

Comment: @tnk479 - Just for fun, I passed the ILoggerFactory into the Confiugre method and called AddLog4Net() as well and it still results in no log file unless I use the XmlConfigurator - the bit about the Log4NetCore configuration section is only if you want to use Log4NetProviderOptions and that still depends on the config file being found by log4net

Comment: Yeah, good call.

Comment: In his asp.net 2.2 example he has this CopyToOutputDirectory set in his project file. Might be something to try. https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/blob/develop/samples/Sample.WebApi_NetCore22/NetCoreWebApp2.2.csproj